# PHP mailer sentfrom error

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to send mail using PHP Mailer but there is an issue with `setfrom()` method

In `$mail->setFrom('abcd@abcd.com', 'Jay');`

When I use domain name .com mail gets sent and received properly

But when I use . co domain name example `$mail->setFrom('abcd@abcd.co', 'Jay');`
Its doesn't show any error and says mail sent successfully but mail isn't received on my account.Tried changing google privacy settings.

**Note**:Not using SMPT kept it to false using default settings

**Update**:Ok so the thing is It is working but the emails are being receive after hours and hours if I use .co but when I use .com email are received immediately.
Probably server problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem was the server (bluehost)

What was happening is whenever the `setFrom()` had an email address whose sub domain was not '.com' eg: " abcd@abcd.co,abcd@abcd.in" the mail was being received after several hours.

It would work normally if setfrom() was set to a normal address eg: a@gmail.com .

Probably a server issue.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a known problem that's been answered before: gmail does not allow setting arbitrary from addresses. You can preconfigure aliases in settings, but you can't simply start using them at the sending client. You can see the submission conversation by setting `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;`, but if it's sending successfully, PHPMailer has no involvement beyond that point.

Comment: Well I am not using smtp to send I have kept it to false I am using the default settings.Tried changing gmail setting to show less secure but no luck

Comment: This also explains it - if gmail is rejecting your message, you may never find out about it. You need to look in your mail server logs. Using SMTP from PHPMailer can make things much more transparent, but there are some downsides to it, mainly that PHPMailer isn't an MTA.